Mosaico image links problem
I'm looking for help to debug a Mosaico issue. This is Mosaico 3.6.1725615009, CiviCRM 5.78.3, Wordpress 6.7.1. There is something wrong with the directory links but I haven't been able to pin it down.
Specifically, we can upload an image into a Mosaico email, or select one from the gallery, and the image only appears in the template as a blank box. A test email with an image selected from the gallery does display the image, but a newly uploaded image does not work. Same with the 'preview as HTML', it works with an image from the gallery but not a new image.
When I look at the server, I see the new file in [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/images/uploads. But the gallery is displaying files in [civicrm.files]/upload.
The upload settings are:
Temporary files: [civicrm.files]/upload/
Image directory: [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/
I don't see any file permission problems.
This started to happen when I upgraded Mosaico from 3.5 recently. Until then it was working correctly. Any suggestions welcome.
Edit: I reverted back to the previous version of Mosaico extension, and there is no change in the behavior, so perhaps it's not a Mosaico issue. However I haven't changed any Civi settings in this time frame, and I am still baffled.

I found the cause of the problem is a fatal error in an unrelated plugin, which for some reason showed up as a failure in Mosaico. I'm contacting the plugin author for help.
